# What are Data Replication Frameworks? What's its usage?

Tags: replication

I have came across a term Data Replication framework but quite difficult to grasp its concepts. I came across when I tried studying about the architecture of Instagram. Although this might be a broad concept, I would like to learn much about this. Explanations appreciated.

Would keep this thread just for learning purposes.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be easily answerable and isn't on-topic as a specific programming question for Stack Overflow. I'd suggest looking into replication options and documentation for some of the databases you originally tagged in this question. The [Instagram Engineering blog](https://instagram-engineering.com/) is a good starting point if you are researching Instagram in particular.